# Scaling Policy not executed because its effect does not override in-progress scaling actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling

I have created auto scaling group with launch template and scaling policy which scale out when cpu utilization is over 50 in cloud watch alarm, every time cpu utilization goes above 50 in cloud watch alarm and alarm changes state to in alarm and  it shows error - **Scaling Policy not executed because its effect does not override in-progress scaling actions**, i have looked into scaling activity there is no in progress action, all actions are completed , also i have only given single policy to scale out only still not able to figure out what exactly going wrong